# jQuery not initializing in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, window-resize

I want to add a simple jQuery code on the page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var scrollOnOff = function() {
    var windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (windowWidth < 1900) {
        $('#containerDiv').removeClass('containerDiv-scroll');
    } else if (windowWidth >= 1901) {
        $('#containerDiv').addClass('containerDiv-scroll');
    };
};
$(window).resize(function() {
    scrollOnOff();
});
scrollOnOff();
});
```

But for some reason it doesn't work in IE 8. I've tried some simple solutions to solve this problem, but nothing helps.

Can someone help me to fix this or say what can be the problem, please?

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `var windowWidth = $(window).width();`

Comment: Unfortunately it now helps(

Actually I'm not sure about clientWidth, couz it looks like script not initialized at all or so. But in chrome everything working fine (what a surprise!)...